# Would this touchscreen work with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: driver, screen, touchscreen, android

I'm looking at getting this [659GL-70NP/C/T](http://www.lilliputuk.com/monitors/hdmi/659gl/) touchscreen for my Raspberry Pi but I'm not sure if the touch surface will work with the Raspberry Pi `Android OS`. Will it?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the manufacturer, since the "specifications" don't mention the interface it uses

Comment: CarComputer.co.uk says it uses USB ( http://www.carcomputer.co.uk/index.php?/monitors/hdmi-monitors/lilliput-669gl-70np/c/t-7-hdmi-touch-screen-monitor ) but I'm not sure whether it has RasPi drivers.

Comment: So it goes. If Google doesn't help, your options might be to take the risk or find someplace you can test it yourself. Just plug it in and see what the USB IDs are and if you can see the chip used in the TS. Even Windows device damager should be able to show you these. At least the IDs. So you won't need an actual PI or anything more capable, just a running demo machine.

Comment: On the website noticed it takes 12v to power the screen. The Raspberry pi is 3.5v - 5 v. I do not have a solution, I just wanted to make you aware of the potential problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get this screen to work with the RPi, but on an older thread on Raspberry Pi site (2012AUG02), I found this message from Limor Fried on a suggestion to port Adafruit Arduino code to use in RPi touch screens. [0] I assume any code they use will using the Adafruit RPi distro. [1]

> hang tight folks, we are working a lot of products for the pi,
>   including a touchscreen!
>
> -ladyada

You can read the post here. [2] I'm pretty sure this was also repeated on a RPi Friday video somewhere. I'll add a link when I find it.

**Reference**

[0]  **adafruit**, *"Touch-Screen-Library: Arduino library for 4-wire resistive touchscreens"*

github.com/adafruit/Touch-Screen-Library

[1] **adafruit**, "tweaked distribution for teaching electronics using the Raspberry PI"

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro

[2] **adafruit** reply to **jfornango** *"Tue Sep 18, 2012 4:50 pm"*

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=8983&start=25

Comment: Looks like an old thread, but if you are interested in this, there are a few dozen touchscreen drivers in the mainline linux kernel under `Device Drivers -> Input Device Support -> Touchscreens`; I think you also need a userspace driver for X, eg https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchscreen#Available_X11_drivers There's only one screen mentioned in the RPi wiki: http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Touch_Screen , too bad people haven't added to that...

Comment: thx goldilock. it is an old thread but it'll become important the first real demo's start rolling out. Didnt think to look at the elinux RPi peripheral list.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if the Raspberry Pi has networking support on the DVI port.

The HDMI 1.4 is supposed to support Ethernet on Pin 14 HEC Data-

(Optional, HDMI 1.4+ with Ethernet)

Not that that device has HDMI.  Or even DSI.

I would pass on that and wait for the DSI activation.  PSP I think uses DSI touch screens.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your OS. It should work, but your OS might not have the required drivers. If you're using raspbian I wouldn't, it doesn't have very good video drivers, but android or something else, give it a try, you may have to do some editing to `config.txt`.

Comment: The question specifically states the OS. What's the point of adding a non-answer?

Comment: For others with the same question